# java equivalent of python regex

Tags: java, android, python, regex

I am new to android development. And now i am struck with a regex pattern. I had tried many things but in vain.

I am trying to find the java equivalent of  the regular expression `"r'\^\d+\~[A-Za-z~ ]+'"`  which is written in python.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Actually I want to parse the string :

> "0~XYZ~Xamp Vampire~XMP~Vampire Cenet~~2013-7-9-16-39-25~~~~^12345~VAMPIRE CITY~Vampire City~VMC~Vampire Center~VPC~Xamp Center~XMPC~Xamper VC~XMVX~07.50~09.45~01.55~1111111~~~~~~~~0001001000~~~~~~~~~~~MAIL_EXPRESS~4640~1~0~0~2013-07-08~2018-07-08~84~43~MAIL_EXPRESS:84:1085,1085,675,0,575,0:650,650,415,315,355,965:460,460,295,260,250,720:245,245,165,100,145,345:280,280,190,0,165,0:135,135,90,90,80,170:55,45,40,10,35,45:0,0,0,0,0,0:40,30,40,0,40,40~0~0~~60~1~6303~~~Intercity Express~~1~SR~~BG~~~10010~,,En:,,GS:,,GSLRD:,,GS:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:D,D1,2S:C,C1,CC:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,GSLR:~0~"

I wrote the regex in python as `reg1=re.compile(r'\^\d+\~[A-Za-z~ ]+')` and it gives me a result as `['^12345~VAMPIRE CITY~Vampire City~VMC~Vampire Center~VPC~Xamp Center~XMPC~Xamper VC~XMVX~']` as an array. I just want to reproduce this in java. I tried many combinations and what npinti suggests, but failed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three hours of hunt (since am a beginner in android), I find the correct thing, finally!

```
String myRegex = "[\\^]\\d{5}~[A-Za-z~ ]+";
```

This gives me what I need. Thanks to all those who tried to help me :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should work: `r'\\^\\d+~[A-Za-z~ ]+`. It should match an `r` followed by a `'`, which is then followed by a `^`, one or more digits followed by a `~` and one or more repetitions of letters, `~` and a white space.

In java the `\` is a special character, so it needs to be escaped, this is why we have the extra `\` in front of the `\` required by the regex engine.

EDIT: I was unable to find python regular expressions starting with `r'`, so I am assuming that you need to match that.

If this is not the case, just use `\\^\\d+~[A-Za-z~ ]+`.

EDIT:

This code seems to be working:

```
        String file = "0~XYZ~Xamp Vampire~XMP~Vampire Cenet~~2013-7-9-16-39-25~~~~^12345~VAMPIRE CITY~Vampire City~VMC~Vampire Center~VPC~Xamp Center~XMPC~Xamper VC~XMVX~07.50~09.45~01.55~1111111~~~~~~~~0001001000~~~~~~~~~~~MAIL_EXPRESS~4640~1~0~0~2013-07-08~2018-07-08~84~43~MAIL_EXPRESS:84:1085,1085,675,0,575,0:650,650,415,315,355,965:460,460,295,260,250,720:245,245,165,100,145,345:280,280,190,0,165,0:135,135,90,90,80,170:55,45,40,10,35,45:0,0,0,0,0,0:40,30,40,0,40,40~0~0~~60~1~6303~~~Intercity Express~~1~SR~~BG~~~10010~,,En:,,GS:,,GSLRD:,,GS:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:D,D1,2S:C,C1,CC:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,2S:,,GSLR:~0~";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\^\\d+\\~[A-Za-z~ ]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
```

Yields:

```
^12345~VAMPIRE CITY~Vampire City~VMC~Vampire Center~VPC~Xamp Center~XMPC~Xamper VC~XMVX~
Finished
```

The whole `r'` thing seems to have given me some trouble and I actually omitted an initial `\\` in my previous edit (which has now been fixed). I essentially used the same regular expression which @Kent suggested (so his should be the answer which should be accepted). I simply added some java code to better help you get what you wan :).

Comment: I believe the `r` is not a part of regex in python. :)

Comment: @Kent: I was unable to find any example where the `r'` is used, so I assumed that the OP wanted to match that as well. If this is not the case, then I ammended for that as well, which is essentially what you posted.

Comment: It is ok. you can find it here:http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals Actually, OP confuses us a bit. He said a regex in py. I believe he meant `r'\^\d+\~[A-Za-z~ ]+'` but he quoted the whole thing again. It could mislead people to think the text between the double quotes is the regex in python...

Comment: @Kent I understand. If this is the case then your answer is correct. Upvote from me :).

Comment: r is for Raw-string - not a regex part :-)

Comment: @DevTest Use backtick (`) for quoting code. Ppl get less confused.

Comment: I can't vote you up since i have lesser reputation, but thank you very much

Comment: @DevTest: Under the score of a the answers there should be a green very good mark. Just tick the one which solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

you just replace backslash with double-backslash. try this string (in java) as regex:

```
String myRegex = "\\^\\d+\\~[A-Za-z~ ]+";
```

Comment: I can't vote you up since i have lesser reputation, but thank you very much